# Find maximum length of good path in a grid

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Given is a N*N grid.Now we need to find a good path of maximum length , where good path is defined as follow :

1. Good path always start from a cell marked as 0
2. We are only allowed to move Left,Right,Up Or Down
3. If the value of ith cell is say A, then value of next cell in the path must be A+1.

Now given these few conditions, I need to find out the length of maximum path that can be made. Also I need to count such paths that are of maximum length.

Example : Let N=3 and we have 3*3 matrix as follow :

```
0 3 2               
3 0 1               
2 1 0
```

Then maximum good path length here is 3 and the count of such good paths is 4.

0 **3 2**
3 **0 1**
2 1 0

0 3 2
**3 0** 1
**2 1** 0

0 **3** **2**
3 0 **1**
2 1 **0**

0 3 2
**3** 0 1
**2 1 0**

Comment: are there any requirements for memory usage or CPU efficiency?

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko Yeah, The time complexity and space complexity must be accpetable and computable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is a variation of [Longest Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), however your restrictions make this problem much easier, since the graph is actually a [Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), and thus the problem is solveable efficiently.

Define the directed graph `G=(V,E)` as following:

- `V = { all cells in the matrix}` (sanity check: |V| = N^2)
- `E = { (u,v) | u is adjacent to v AND value(u) + 1 = value(v) }`

Note that the resulting graph from the above definition is a DAG, because you cannot have any cycles, since it will result in having some edge `e= (u,v)` such that `value(u) > value(v)`.

Now, you only need to find [longest path in a DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Acyclic_graphs_and_critical_paths) from any starting point. This is done by [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) on the graph, and then using Dynamic Programming:

```
init:
for every source in the DAG:
D(v) = 0            if value(v) = 0
       -infinity    otherwise
step:
for each node v from first to last (according to topological sort)
   D(v) = max{D(u) + 1 | for each edge (u,v) }
```

When you are done, find the node `v` with maximal value `D(v)`, this is the length of the longest "good path".

Finding the path itself is done by rerolling the above, retracing your steps back from the maximal D(v) until you reach back the initial node with value 0.

Complexity of this approach is `O(V+E) = O(n^2)`

---

Since you are looking for the number of longest paths, you can modify this solution a bit to count the number of paths reached to each node, as follows:

```
Topological sort the nodes, let the sorted array be arr (1)
For each node v from start to end of arr:
   if value(v) = 0:
        set D(v) = 1 
   else
        sum = 0
        for each u such that (u,v) is an edge: (2)
            sum = sum + D(u) 
        D(v) = sum
```

The above will find you for each node `v` the number of "good paths" `D(v)` that reaches it. All you have to do now, is find the maximal value `x` that has sum node `v` such that `value(v) = x` and `D(v) > 0`, and sum the number of paths reaching any node with `value(v)`:

```
max = 0
numPaths = 0
for each node v:
    if value(v) == max:
         numPaths = numPaths + D(v)
    else if value(v) > max AND D(v) > 0:
         numPaths = D(v)
         max = value(v)
return numPaths
```

Notes:
(1)  - a "regular" sort works here to, but it will take O(n^2logn) time, and topological sort takes O(n^2) time

(2) Reminder, (u,v) is an edge if: (1) `u` and `v` are adjacent (2) value(u) + 1 = value(v)

Comment: I need not find the path I only need maximum length and the count of such length paths

Comment: @user3840069 The maximal value of D(v) is the length of the longest path

Comment: Yeah that point i got pretty well. But how many paths will be their with this length ?

Comment: @user3840069 You can do a BFS on the reversed graph (reverse nodes direction), and instead of finding a single route, maintain a counter and multiple it by the number of choices you have every step. The resulting count will be the number of choices to get to each maximal D(v) node. Repeat and summarize for each such maximal node, and you should get the count of longest paths

Comment: Can you provide your implementation inC++ or java ?

Comment: @user3840069 I cannot provide an implementation, it will just take too long for me, but I editted to show you how to modify the old approach to find number of longest paths

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple Breadth-First Search.

First find all cells marked 0. (This is O(N<sup>2</sup>).) On each such cell put a walker. Each walker carries a number 'p' initialized to 1.

Now iterate:

All walkers stand on cells with the same number k. Each walker looks for neighboring cells (left, right, up or down) marked with k+1.

If no walker sees such a cell, **the search is over. The length of the longest path is k, and the number of such paths is the sum of the p's of all the walkers.**

If some walkers see such numbers, kill any walkers that don't.

Each walker moves into a good neighboring cell. If a walker sees more than one good cell, it divides into as many walkers as there are good cells, and one goes into each. (Each "child" has the same `p` value its "parent" had.) If two or more walkers meet in the same cell (i.e. if more than one path led to that cell) then they combine into a single walker, whose 'p' value is the sum of their 'p' values.

This algorithm is O(N<sup>2</sup>), since no cell can be visited more than once, and the number of walkers cannot exceed the number of cells.

Comment: A C++/ Java code will better explain your approach. Or pseudocode can also serve the purpose.I am not getting what you are trying to say. Also we need to count number of such paths

Comment: @user3840069: We did count the number of such paths. Are you familiar with the idea of a Breadth-First Search?

Comment: Yeah I know how BFS works.But just for better understanding code will explain things pretty well

Comment: If you want to understand this solution -- which is really quite a simple BFS -- then you must put in a little bit of effort. If you want someone to write your code for you, there are sites like elance that can help.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using ActionScript, hope it's readable. I think it is working correctly but I may have missed something.

```
const N:int = 9; // field size
const MIN_VALUE:int = 0; // start value

var field:Array = [];

// create field - not relevant to the task
var probabilities:Array = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
for (var i:int = 0; i < N * N; i++) field.push(probabilities[int(Math.random() * probabilities.length)]);//RANGE));
print_field();

// initial chain fill. We will find any chains of adjacent 0-1 elements.
var chain_list:Array = [];
for (var offset:int = 0; offset < N * N - 1; offset++) {
    if (offset < N * N - N) { // y coordinate is not the lowest
        var chain:Array = find_chain(offset, offset + N, MIN_VALUE);
        if (chain) chain_list.push(chain);
    }
    if ((offset % N) < N - 1) { // x coordinate is not the rightmost
        chain = find_chain(offset, offset + 1, MIN_VALUE);
        if (chain) chain_list.push(chain);
    }
}

var merged_chain_list:Array = chain_list;
var current_value:int = MIN_VALUE + 1;

// for each found chain, scan its higher end for more attached chains
// and merge them into new chain if found
while(chain_list.length) {
    chain_list = [];
    for (i = 0; i < merged_chain_list.length; i++) {
        chain = merged_chain_list[i];
        offset = chain[chain.length - 1];

        if (offset < N * N - N) {
            var tmp:Array = find_chain(offset, offset + N, current_value);
            if (tmp) chain_list.push(merge_chains(chain, tmp));
        }
        if (offset > N) {
            tmp = find_chain(offset, offset - N, current_value);
            if (tmp) chain_list.push(merge_chains(chain, tmp));
        }
        if ((offset % N) < N - 1) {
            tmp = find_chain(offset, offset + 1, current_value);
            if (tmp) chain_list.push(merge_chains(chain, tmp));
        }
        if (offset % N) {
            tmp = find_chain(offset, offset - 1, current_value);
            if (tmp) chain_list.push(merge_chains(chain, tmp));
        }
    }

    //save the last merged result if any and try the next value
    if (chain_list.length) {
        merged_chain_list = chain_list;
        current_value++;
    }
}

// final merged list is a list of chains of a same maximum length
print_chains(merged_chain_list);

function find_chain(offset1, offset2, current_value):Array {
    // returns always sorted sorted from min to max
    var v1:int = field[offset1];
    var v2:int = field[offset2];
    if (v1 == current_value && v2 == current_value + 1) return [offset1, offset2];
    if (v2 == current_value && v1 == current_value + 1) return [offset2, offset1];
    return null;
}

function merge_chains(chain1:Array, chain2:Array):Array {
    var tmp:Array = [];
    for (var i:int = 0; i < chain1.length; i++) tmp.push(chain1[i]);
    tmp.push(chain2[1]);
    return tmp;
}

function print_field():void {
    for (var pos_y:int = 0; pos_y < N; pos_y++) {
        var offset:int = pos_y * N;
        var s:String = "";
        for (var pos_x:int = 0; pos_x < N; pos_x++) {
            var v:int = field[offset++];
            if (v == 0) s += "[0]"; else s += " " + v + " ";
        }
        trace(s);
    }
}

function print_chains(chain_list):void {
    var cl:int = chain_list.length;
    trace("\nchains found: " + cl);
    if (cl) trace("chain length: " + chain_list[0].length);
    for (var i:int = 0; i < cl; i++) {
        var chain:Array = chain_list[i];
        var s:String = "";
        for (var j:int = 0; j < chain.length; j++) s += chain[j] + ":" + field[chain[j]] + " ";
        trace(s);
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
 1  2  1  3  2  2  3  2  4 
 4  3  1  2  2  2 [0][0] 1 
[0][0] 1  2  4 [0] 3  3  1 
[0][0] 5  4  1  1 [0][0] 1 
 2  2  3  4  3  2 [0] 1  5 
 4 [0] 3 [0] 3  1  4  3  1 
 1  2  2  3  5  3  3  3  2 
 3  4  2  1  2  4  4  4  5 
 4  2  1  2  2  3  4  5 [0]

chains found: 2
chain length: 5
23:0 32:1 41:2 40:3 39:4 
33:0 32:1 41:2 40:3 39:4
```

Comment: Can you provide implementation in C++ or java as I don't have any idea of Action Script

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I implemented it in my own Lisp dialect, so the source code is not going to help you that much :-) ...</strike>

EDIT: Added a Python version too.

anyway the idea is:

- write a function `paths(i, j) --> (maxlen, number)` that returns maximal length of paths starting from `(i, j)` and how many of them are present..
- this function is recursive and looking at neighbors of `(i, j)` with value `M[i][j]+1` will call `paths(ni, nj)` to get the result for valid neighbors
- if the maximal length for a neighbor is bigger than current maximal length you set a new current maximal length and reset the counter
- if the maximal length is the same as current then add the counter to the total
- if the maximal length is smaller just ignore that neighbor result
- cache the result of the computation for the cell (this is very important!). In my version the code is split in two mutually recursive functions: `paths` that checks the cache first and calls `compute-paths` otherwise; `compute-paths` calls `paths` when processing neighbors. The caching of a recursive call is roughly equivalent to an explicit Dynamic Programming approach, but sometimes easier to implement.

To compute the final result you basically do the same computation but adding up the result for all `0` cells instead of considering neighbors.

Note that the number of different paths can become huge, and that's why enumerating all of them is not a viable option and caching/DP is a must: for example for a `N=20` matrix with values `M[i][j] = i+j` there are 35,345,263,800 maximal paths of length 38.

This algorithm is O(N^2) in time (each cell is visited at most once) and requires O(N^2) space for the cache and for the recursion. Of course you cannot expect to get anything better than this given that the input is composed of N^2 numbers itself and you need at least to read them to compute an answer.

```
(defun good-paths (matrix)
  (let** ((N (length matrix))
          (cache (make-array (list N N)))
          (#'compute-paths (i j)
            (let ((res (list 0 1))
                  (count (1+ (aref matrix i j))))
              (dolist ((ii jj) (list (list (1+ i) j) (list (1- i) j)
                                     (list i (1+ j)) (list i (1- j))))
                (when (and (< -1 ii N) (< -1 jj N)
                           (= (aref matrix ii jj) count))
                  (let (((maxlen num) (paths ii jj)))
                    (incf maxlen)
                    (cond
                      ((< (first res) maxlen)
                       (setf res (list maxlen num)))
                      ((= (first res) maxlen)
                       (incf (second res) num))))))
              res))
          (#'paths (i j)
            (first (or (aref cache i j)
                       (setf (aref cache i j)
                             (list (compute-paths i j))))))
          (res (list 0 0)))
    (dotimes (i N)
      (dotimes (j N)
        (when (= (aref matrix i j) 0)
          (let (((maxlen num) (paths i j)))
            (cond
              ((< (first res) maxlen)
               (setf res (list maxlen num)))
              ((= (first res) maxlen)
               (incf (second res) num)))))))
    res))
```

### Edit

The following is a transliteration of the above in Python, that should be much easier to understand if you never saw Lisp before...

```
def good_paths(matrix):
    N = len(matrix)
    cache = [[None]*N for i in xrange(N)] # an NxN matrix of None

    def compute_paths(i, j):
        maxlen, num = 0, 1
        count = 1 + matrix[i][j]
        for (ii, jj) in ((i+1, j), (i-1, j), (i, j-1), (i, j+1)):
            if 0 <= ii < N and 0 <= jj < N and matrix[ii][jj] == count:
                nh_maxlen, nh_num = paths(ii, jj)
                nh_maxlen += 1
                if maxlen < nh_maxlen:
                    maxlen = nh_maxlen
                    num = nh_num
                elif maxlen == nh_maxlen:
                    num += nh_num
        return maxlen, num

    def paths(i, j):
        res = cache[i][j]
        if res is None:
            res = cache[i][j] = compute_paths(i, j)
        return res

    maxlen, num = 0, 0
    for i in xrange(N):
        for j in xrange(N):
            if matrix[i][j] == 0:
                c_maxlen, c_num = paths(i, j)
                if maxlen < c_maxlen:
                    maxlen = c_maxlen
                    num = c_num
                elif maxlen == c_maxlen:
                    num += c_num
    return maxlen, num
```

Comment: Can you provide your implementation in C++ or java ? As i dont understand Lisp

Comment: @user3840069: I've added a Python version that should be trivial to understand if you know C++ or Java...