# Given a matrix of ints, find the longest consecutive snake of incrementing by 1 numbers

Tags: algorithm

Basically, you have something like this:

```
0 9 5 3'
4 1 5' 4'
5 7' 6' 9
2 8' 5 10
```

In this case, the longest snake would be 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8. I put ' behind the numbers in this to help show it visually.

You can go both horizontally and vertically. The matrix can be n x m, so there isn't really a limit to the number of rows and columns.

What is the most optimal way to figure this out?

I've thought about starting at position n/2 and m/2, then recursively doing breadth-first search and keeping track of the max interval I can find. I'm not sure how to best tackle it.

Comment: Think about a "diff(...)" command taking the difference between two adjacent numbers in the matrix and checking if that difference is 1. In Python, e.g., this is a command (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html).

Comment: @denvar while "diff(...)" is definitely something you would use when comparing elements that are side by side, it doesn't help the larger picture of how one would go about optimally traversing a matrix to find the longest snake.

Comment: Can numbers be repeated in the matrix?

Comment: As in the above example, numbers can appear multiple times in the matrix. However, you can not do something like 2 -> 3 -> 3 -> 4. It must be increasing at each time.

Comment: I would start with a DFS - walking up *and* down from the start node - where I would remove every visited node from the set of nodes that could begin the DFS (because if it was visited it must already be part of a snake).

Comment: Is the matrix given to you or do you generate it yourself?

Comment: Assume it is randomly generated.

Comment: This is basically the same question, without the restriction of starting from 0  as the question in the linked question. This restrictment is not a major issue, and the linked thread esplains pretty well how this should be approached. (Major difference is giving every source in the DAG value 0, not only those with value of cell 0)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a graph where nodes are matrix positions and vertices are pointing from a number N to a N+1 neighbour.

Once the graph is built, your problem amounts to finding one of the longest paths in this graph.

Comment: Finding longest path in a graph is not easy. In a DAG however.... (More details in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28397815/572670)